# jQuery - if select option value equal with a data add class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a select box with 3 option, and a div with 3  that they has data attribute.
now i want each option that has selected=seclected and also value (number) equal with a data then add class to

**for example:**

if option selected / and value = with  data:

```
<option value="2" selected="selected">
```

do (add class):

```
 <a class="menuitem active" data="2"></a>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3g8qsph/5/)**

```
$("#myselect option").each(function(){
    var num = $('.menucontainer').children('a.menuitem').attr('data');
        if($(this).is(':selected').val()==num){ 
            $('.menucontainer').children('a.menuitem').addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: do you mean http://jsfiddle.net/g8mv0s79/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had many small mistakes. Like

1.) Jquery was not included in fiddle.

2.) `.is` returns a boolean value, and you were doing `$(this).is(':selected').val()`. You should be doing `$(this).is(':selected') && $(this).val()`.

3.) There was `});` extra in the end.

And I think iterating other way arround will be better. Like bellow

```
$('.menucontainer .menuitem').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('data')==$('#myselect :selected').val())
        $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/d3g8qsph/19/)

Comment: Thanks for your anwer, sorry for mistakes,,.
but if you see again your demo, you'll see all has active class, i want only that a that equal with option and that option is selected. on this demo we have only one option that selected.

Comment: Thanks again, but i still have a little problem with this. how about this http://jsfiddle.net/d3g8qsph/29/ ? with two or more selected item?

Comment: @user3815083 then you have to check if it present in any of values. see demo http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/d3g8qsph/32/